# Updating large document in collection causes client to freeze for 6-8 seconds

Tags: meteor, collections, updates

I have a relatively large document in a collection; the document is an object with ~2000 elements, each of which is itself a small object. When I update the document on the server, the client locks up for 6-8 seconds.

I've put in logging that tells me when the server has finished updating the collection, then there is the 6-8 second freeze, and the next thing which happens is that observeChanges runs in the client and everything starts running again.

- I've put in a timeout in the client that logs to the console every 100ms. It stops firing during the delay, so I think none of my client-side javascript is running.
- The delay seems to match the initial load time of the document (I've tried different size documents).
- I'm using Iron Router. I've put logging into the data, waitOn and action functions: they are not firing until after the delay. So I don't think the router is the problem.
- The function that updates the collection is only running on the server, so it's not slow client-side emulation.
- It's not the rendering: if I trigger the update client-side only, the page re-renders fast.
- I've checked pretty carefully and I don't think any of my client code is requesting that document, the only find() for it runs at startup, and it's not the autorun.
- I've put logging into my publish function: the collection isn't being republished. I'm not running autopublish.

Any thoughts what might be the problem or ideas for how I could investigate further? Is it as simple as an unavoidable synch time when documents are updated? I need all of the data, so while I could restructure it, I can't get rid of any of it.

Comment: Can you try logging Meteor.Status() on the client in a reactive computation to see what it reports? Do you have a rough idea of a mean number of bytes in the collections you are syncing? Last question, when you update the collection are you swapping out the entire data set and if so could you possibly use $set or any combination of selectors and modifiers to be more granular about your updates?

Comment: Thank you, some interesting ideas to check out. I may also work around the problem by stringifying the data and storing it as as single text document, then parsing it when I read it from the database. Although there are a lot of objects in the data, they are very small so it packs down fairly compactly (wish I'd thought of that sooner...)